# Hybrid Connection Listener windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, azure-hybrid-connections

I am new to C# and Azure Hybrid Connections, so please be kind.

We have a console app in c# that uses the Hybrid Connection Listener that waits for connection requests.  When a request comes in with the data, it does stuff (technical term) with the data.  Also the request is to write it using **.Net Core.**

I have a request to change the console app into a Windows Service.  I cannot seem to find a simple windows service sample.  Can anyone point me to one?  My problem is that the service does not stop to listen, it just continues on through the worker loop.

Can someone point me in the right direction please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting Console app to Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19558801/converting-console-app-to-windows-service)

Comment: Yes and No.  It does not look like this example would work in .net Core.  Or am i wrong.  It appears that System.ServiceProcess is .net framework.

Comment: I ended up recreating the application as a Worker Service application.  In the worker service I added the hybrid connection listener and it worked as expected.